Нужна запятая или точка с запятой?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в этом предложении можно поставить запятую или нужна точка с запятой? "Врач — травматолог-ортопед,(;) в разное время занимал должности заведующего травматологическим отделением и главного врача".

Надо поставить точку с запятой, похоже на перечень. Кроме того, в первом наименовании есть тире, и его нужно выделить более сильным знаком, чем запятая.

Нужна запятая или точка с запятой?
Я бы поставил точку с запятой.
Почему?
Нужно отделить часть "Врач — травматолог-ортопед" более сильным знаком, чем запятая, чтобы избежать путаницы.
Другое решение
Если хотите запятую поставить, то можно немного изменить предложение:
Врач — травматолог-ортопед, который в разное время занимал должности заведующего травматологическим отделением и главного врача.

Оставленный без ответа вопрос = большая проблема, на этом форуме было 800 неотвеченных вопросов когда я начал отвечать

Неинформативные у вас ответы. При ответах давайте ссылки на правила, определяйте грамматику предложения, приводите примеры из литературы. // Ответов нет на те вопросы. где темы настолько просты, что достаточно комментария. У нас все-таки лингвистический сайт,  для обсуждения нужны проблемные темы. Вот я пишу: похоже на перечень. Почему не отвечаю?  Это версия, надо искать материал по перечням для ответа.
